# SQL Sumar valor de una fila en las demás filas. SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito sumar el resultado de unas filas de sql.
Tengo el siguiente resultado.

```
    Nombre  | Valor
   ----------------- 
    Carlos  |   10
   ----------------- 
    Miguel  |   20
   ----------------- 
            |    2
```

Lo que quiero lograr es sumar el valor del que no tiene nombre en las otras dos filas, dando como resultado

```
    Nombre  |  Valor
   -----------------
    Carlos  |    12
   ----------------- 
    Miguel  |    22
```

Es posible hacerlo?.
No se me ha ocurrido la manera de hacerlo.

Comment: La solution la puedes encontrar aqui:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum Un saludo.

Comment: Por favor, incluye en tu pregunta a) la consulta con la que estás obteniendo el resultado actual. b) ¿que valor está almacenado en el dato _"que no tiene nombre", null, string vacío, otro_? c)¿puede haber varias filas _que no tienen nombre_ o hay garantía que siempre habrá solo una fila?

Comment: La consulta es un procedimiento almacenado muy extenso, estoy dando esos resultados como ejemplo, hay muchos mas campos, pero todo se está agrupando por el nombre. El problema persiste en que en algunas ocaciones el nombre va a estar nulo porque es un elemento general para todos, por ese motivo debe sumarse en todas las demás filas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo utilizando un CTE para derivar ese *valor general* que quieres sumarle al resto de filas.
Dado que en comentarios me has dicho que la consulta es muy compleja, voy a utilizar un primer CTE para *simular* el resultado de esta primera consulta, que bien podrías depositar en una tabla normal o tabla temporal previamente, o bien contener en otro CTE.

Voy a asumir también que pueden haber varias filas con el campo `Nombre` en `null` y que lo que nos interesa sumar es, a su vez, la suma de todas estas filas.

En el CTE `ValorGeneral`, calculo entonces esta suma. Es posible que este CTE devuelva 0 o 1 filas, pero no más.

En la consulta final, hago un `cross join` entre los datos originales y `ValorGeneral`. Te muestro una columna con el valor original y otra con el valor + el valor general. Acá excluyo la(s) fila(s) sin nombre, que ya no me interesan en el resultado.

En la suma, me cuido del caso que `ValorGeneral` no devuelva filas, utilizando la función `coalesce`, de otra forma, el campo devolvería `null`.

```
with
Datos as (
select 'Carlos' Nombre, 10 Valor
union all select 'Miguel', 20
union all select null, 2
)
,
ValorGeneral as (
select SUM(Valor) ValorGeneral
  from Datos
 where Nombre is null
)
select a.Nombre, a.Valor, a.Valor + coalesce(b.ValorGeneral, 0) ValorConValorGeneral
  from Datos a
       cross join ValorGeneral b
 where a.Nombre is not null;
```

Esto produce el siguiente resultado:

```
Nombre Valor       ValorConValorGeneral
------ ----------- --------------------
Carlos 10          12
Miguel 20          22

(2 rows affected)
```

Comment: Gracias, el ejemplo me funcionó, pero cómo sería posible cuando se agrupa por dos valores, (El nombre y una categoría extra), lo coloqué en la consulta y omitió todas las categorías que no tenían algún nombre null y si le sacó la condición de que el nombre no sea nulo no sabe suma los nulos en todas las filas, independiente de la categoría.

Comment: Por la naturaleza del caso, si nos vamos en comentarios vamos a cambiar todo, y creo que tu pregunta original está respondida, con los datos de ejemplo que diste en la pregunta y las aclaraciones solicitadas. Si tu caso es distinto (por ejemplo, más complejo), mi sugerencia es que hagas una nueva pregunta y que incluyas los datos suficientes para que la respuesta contemple ese caso. Mi sugerencia es siempre incluir una muestra de los datos de entrada y los datos de salida que se desea obtener, con una explicación de cómo llegar a ellos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso haré

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.SomeNumt,
       SUM(t2.SomeNumt) AS SUM
FROM t t1
INNER JOIN t t2 ON t1.id >= t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id,
         t1.SomeNumt
ORDER BY t1.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/abdce/1